# Grails 3 - Gradle: Binary file gets corrupted during build on Heroku

Tags: grails, heroku, gradle, grails-3.0

I am trying to use the Google Rest API from a Heroku instance. I am having problems with my certificate file, but everything works as expected locally.

**The certificate is a PKCS 12 certificate, and the exception I get is:**

> java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=111, too
>   big.

I finally found the source of this problem. Somewhere along the way the certificate file is modified, locally it is 1732 bytes but on the Heroku instance it is 3024 bytes. But I have no idea when this occurs. I build with the same command locally (./gradlew stage) and execute the resulting jar with the same command.

The file is stored in grails-app/conf, I don't know any better place to put it. I am reading it using `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(...)`

I found similar problems can occur when using Maven with resource filtering. But I haven't found any signs of Grails or Gradle doing the same kind of resource filtering.

Does anyone have any clues about what this can be?